# how to set/change canvasBitmap height and width in win2d UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

What I have tried is?

```
CanvasBitmap CanvasBitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender,@"Assets\xyz.png");
CanvasBitmap.Size.Height = 100;
CanvasBitmap.Size.Width = 300;
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(CanvasBitmap,Vector);
```

but I can't change the width and height of canvasbitmap.I need to change the Width and height of drawable image dynamically in runtime.Can anyone help me?I Don't want to change canvasControl width and height!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

But what you can do is, you can apply scaling to the bitmap:

```
CanvasBitmap CanvasBitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender,@"Assets\xyz.png");
args.DrawingSession.Transform = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(2);
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(CanvasBitmap,Vector);
```